# Adding Apache NiFi to existing Hortonworks HDP Cluster

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi, ambari

I have a 6-node-cluster running Hortonworks HDP 2.5.3 and Ambari 2.4.2.0

I want to install Apache NiFi on this cluster. When looking in the [documentation](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF2/HDF-2.0.1/bk_ambari-installation/content/system-requirements.html), the following line jumps to my eyes:

> 1.1. Interoperability Requirements
>
> You cannot install HDF on a system where HDP is already installed.

I wonder how I can install NiFi on my cluster. I would like to manage it with Ambari too, if possible.

Should I just go ahead and install the standalone version of NiFi and changing the port to something else than 8080, which is in use by Ambari? The problem is that I'd have to install it on every node and this process is not automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can only install one stack into a given Ambari instance, and there is an HDP stack which does not include NiFi, and an HDF stack which includes NiFi, Kafka, Storm, and Ranger. So you need a second Ambari instance where you can install the HDF stack. You also can't share nodes between two Ambaris because there can only be one Ambari agent running on a node.

There might be enhancements in future Ambari releases to improve this situation, but for now if you are limited to using your 6 HDP nodes then you would have to install/manage NiFi manually using the RPM or TAR.

Answer (score 1):

As of HDP 2.6.1 it is possible to install HDF components on an HDP cluster. See https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.0.1.1/bk_installing-hdf-and-hdp/content/ch_install-ambari.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the latest HDP 3.0, it can add HDF 3.2  and work together with NiFi